# Create a new instace class in a JSF EL expression

Tags: jsf, object, instance, el

Is it possible to pass a generic class instance to a method in JSF EL expression ?

For example something like this:

```
#{beanController.someMethod(new ClassToInstance())}
```

It should be very useful for methods which have generic parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The normal procedure is to make `ClassToInstance` a managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ClassToInstance {}
```

Or when you're preferring CDI:

```
@Named
public class ClassToInstance {}
```

Then you can just use:

```
#{beanController.someMethod(classToInstance)}
```